# comment.user.username not working on show.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-routes, ruby-on-rails-7

i'mtrying a simple feature where a user can comment on inquest post , but comment .user.username is not working ,it's rendering comment.user but does not support user attributes

```
create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "content"
t.integer "inquest_id"
t.integer "user_id", null: false
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.index ["inquest_id"], name: "index_comments_on_inquest_id"
t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"
end
```

comment_model

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :inquest 
belongs_to :user
end
```

user_model is simple with has many comments association

comments create method of controller

```
  def create

@comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

pp comment_params
@inquest = Inquest.find(params[:inquest_id])
@comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
@comment.inquest = @inquest
@comment.user = current_user
respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.save
    format.js do
      @inquest = Inquest.find(params[:inquest_id])

    end
  else
    format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

I'm rendering comments in inquest's show.html.erb

```
Showing /Users/zunairaihsan/Desktop/fyp_ed_bolt/app/views/inquests/show.html.erb 
   where line #123 raised:

 undefined method `user_name' for nil:NilClass
```

I've tried most of the ways possible , but it's not working.please let me know where I'm wrong

Comment: To find `nil` values in your views use inspect `comment.user.inspect`, otherwise you're probably missing the broken comment and only seeing the comments that have a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, in `inquests/show.html.erb` you're displaying multiple comments, something like

```rb
<%= @inquest.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.user.user_name %>
  <%= comment.content %>
<% end %>
```

Many comments will render without issue. `Comment` model and database doesn't allow `user_id` to be `nil`.

But looks like one comment's `user_id` doesn't have a corresponding `id` in users table. When you try to figure out what's going on and remove `user_name`

```rb
<%= @inquest.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.user %>
  <%= comment.content %>
<% end %>
```

Sneaky broken comment probably doesn't show you anything, `comment.user` is `nil`, and because you have no validation on `comment.content` it could also be  `nil`.

First, get rid of comments without `user` to verify this is the issue:

```
# this is fast enough for a few thousand comments
>> Comment.find_each { |comment| comment.destroy unless comment.user }
```

After this `inquests/show.html.erb` should be working.

To make sure this doesn't happen again:

```
class User
  # this will delete all `user.comments` when you destroy `user`
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  # ...
end
```

To really make sure this doesn't happen again:

```
class CreateComment < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
      
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

With `foreign_key` constraint, your database will not let you destroy a user if they have comments. This works in tandem with `dependent: :destroy`. If you delete a user and rails automatically destroys all `user.comments`, then database will not complain.

Probably do the same for `inquest` as well if it's not optional.

Also comments without `content` are not really comments:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :inquest 
  belongs_to :user

  validates :content, presence: true
end
```

Comment: thanks much Alex , this cleared things for me , I was rendering user_name and content  without making sure that comment persited or not , and after applying conditions it worked for me.